# data points transformation to be used by DFT

Tags: fft, dft

rather simple question for those who deeply understand Fourier Transform:
so suppose that I have a data series of values [5,2,4,1,0,6,3,7]
and I want to calculate Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) for given set of data points.
According to wiki DFT uses as input complex numbers and outputs also complex numbers, so question is how to convert / transform data points -> input for DFT ?

Comment: Those real-valued data points are simply complex numbers whose imaginary part is zero. Exactly how they are represented depends on the language and DFT implementation (e.g. some languages have built-in type for complex numbers, other would represent it as a pair of floating point numbers).

Comment: kick start with known good input data so begin by obtaining the sequence of floating points generated from a sine wave across say 100 full cycles ... give yourself at least several data samples per cycle ... feed that array of points into your FFT api call and examine the output array ... you know you are in the ball park once you have confirmed the frequency of the input sine wave appears as a spike in the amplitude in the corresponding frequency bin element of that output array

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about basic math, not about programming.

Comment: Cris, maybe I didn't make it clear but this question is programming related - no body today is calculating dft by using calculator :) i've got already algorithm implemented but real concern is how it can be used on real data. This question is worth answearing because there are many developers how wants to use fourier to solve problems but they dont know how to connect all pieces of this puzzle.